# Independent cell width within a grid layout

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

Is it possible to have independent cell widths within a grid layout in CSS?

I'd like to have the following layout:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+
|           |               |   A   |
|           +---------------+-------+
|           |                       |
|           +-------------------+---+
|           |                   | B |
+-----------+-------------------+---+
```

Please, note that cells A and B are of different width.

In addition for cells A and B being of different size, I'd need cell A to be as large as its content while cell B has an static size.

So far I have this code:

```html
<article class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3 h-106">
  <div class="row-span-3" />
  <div />
  <div>A</div>
  <div class="col-span-2" />
  <div />
  <div>B</div>
</article>
```

This piece of code renders the table as shown but with cells A and B bonded together.

I've been searching on internet but I can't seem to find any CSS property that would allow me to do so. I've also been thinking on potential alternatives and I've come with a couple:

- Make the grid to have 2 columns only and use flex layout inside the upper and lower cells.
- Make the grid to have 4 columns where the last one is fixed to the size of cell B and the the 3rd one is used to add space to cell A (a col-span).

I'm not sure either of those approaches work or if there is a better one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a grid container uses tracks to align its children, I'd use flexbox in the elements containing A and B. See below.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(2ch) 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.container > div {
  outline: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.lhs {
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  width: 100px;
}

.one, .three {
  display: flex;
}

:where(.one, .three) > div {
  flex-grow:1;
}

.one > div:last-child {
  flex-grow:0;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

.three > div:last-child {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <div class='lhs'></div>
  <div class='one'>
    <div></div>
    <div>A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three">
    <div></div>
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Cool! That worked perfectly, thank you. The key point was understanding what you said: `a grid container uses tracks to align its children`